# how do i create a local database table in visual studio 2012 and connect connection string in web form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Keyword not supported: `'database1.mdf;integrated security'`.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.ArgumentException:` Keyword not supported: `'database1.mdf;integrated security'`.

Source Error:

```
 public static DataSet fetchdata(string str)
 {            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Sourc(LocalDB)\v11.0;   
 Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=&quot;Database1.mdf;Integrated    Security=True;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
```

Comment: i think you missed to include 'DataDirectory' before Database1.mdf which leads your reported exception. I am not sure about it. I used to add connection string like this in web.config - 'Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=false;Connect Timeout=100;'. Better check your syntax too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have wrongly entered the connection string in your code. This below code works for me every time.

```
string ConnString = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=false;Connect Timeout=100;";
```